# Counting all descendants in a family tree (python dictionary)

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I'm kind of beating my head against a wall here and I'm hoping that someone on stackoverflow can help me.
Let's say I have a python dictionary that looks like:

```
{
    'Son1': 'Father',
    'Son2': 'Father',
    'Father': 'Grandfather',
    'Grandfather': 'Great Grandfather',
    'Uncle': 'Grandfather',
    'Cousin': 'Uncle',
}
```

Right, so each key is a person and the corresponding value is that person's parent. All I want to do at the moment is find out how many *total descendants* a given person has.
I've got a pretty simple function that finds and returns a list of a given person's immediate children.

```
def get_kids(person, dictionary):
    kids = []
    for key in dictionary:
        if dictionary[key] == person:
            kids.append(key)
    return kids
```

Which works fine. From there, I keep thinking that all I need to do is write a recursive function that's something like:

```
def descendants(person, dictionary, count):
    kids = get_kids(person, dictionary)
    count = count + len(kids)
    for kid in kids:
         descendants(kid, dictionary, count)
    return count
```

But this doesn't work. I think because the 'count' variable resets at the end of a 'line' of descendants, instead of being a running total. e.g. If I run:

```
descendants('Grandfather', familydictionary, 0)
```

I get back a value of 2 (instead of the hoped-for 5). Presumably, the count reaches 4 when the function is exploring the 'Father' line, but then drops back down to 3 when it explores the 'Uncle' line, instead. And then, I suppose, the count drops all the way back to 2 when the function finds that 'Cousin' has no kids?
I often struggle with these kinds of recursion problems. What I want to do is pretty straightforward: check if a person has kids and count them, check if their kids have kids and count them, add them to the total ... keep going until there are no more kids. But I get very muddled when I try to actually, well, write the code that does that.
Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually use the value returned by the recursive call. And passing `count` *in* isn't necessary or useful. It's being passed by value, so changing it inside one level of your recursion won't affect the parent calls at all. Rather:

```
def descendants(person, dictionary):
    count = 0
    for kid in get_kids(person, dictionary):
         count += 1 + descendants(kid, dictionary)
    return count
```

Comment: This works! But, geez, I am mystified. Can you expound more on count "being passed by value"? I would have thought that, if you put "count = 0" at the start of the function, then every time descendants gets called, count will be knocked back to zero and will never increase ... but that's obviously wrong. I don't quite get it. But, in any case, thank you.

Comment: @jmaloney13 Each time descendants calls itself is an entirely new "copy" of the function, with its own values for all variables. So e.g. you call it with "Grandfather" and the "Grandfather-count" starts at zero, which calls the "Father" copy, which _also_ starts at zero, adds up to two, and returns that. The "Grandfather" count thus goes up to 3 (1 for Father and 2 from the Sons), then it calls the "Uncle" copy which similarly starts at zero and returns 2; finally the "Grandfather" copy adds that to the existing 3 value and returns a 5.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sum the descendants of each descendant.

```
>>> tree = {
...     'Son1': 'Father',
...     'Son2': 'Father',
...     'Father': 'Grandfather',
...     'Grandfather': 'Great Grandfather',
...     'Uncle': 'Grandfather',
...     'Cousin': 'Uncle',
... }
>>> def descendants(person: str, tree: dict[str, str]) -> int:
...     return sum(
...         1 + descendants(child, tree)
...         for child, parent in tree.items() 
...         if parent == person
...     )
...
>>> descendants("Father", tree)
2
>>> descendants("Grandfather", tree)
5
```

If you want a list of the actual descendants, you can use the same basic structure but sum the lists instead of the counts.  This also makes it easier to visualize how the summing leads to the final solution for the recursive case:

```
>>> def descendants(person: str, tree: dict[str, str]) -> list[str]:
...     return sum((
...         [child] + descendants(child, tree)
...         for child, parent in tree.items()
...         if parent == person
...     ), [])
...
>>> descendants("Father", tree)
['Son1', 'Son2']
>>> descendants("Uncle", tree)
['Cousin']
>>> descendants("Grandfather", tree)
['Father', 'Son1', 'Son2', 'Uncle', 'Cousin']
```

i.e.:

```
descendants("Father", tree) == [] + ["Son1"] + ["Son2"]
descendants("Uncle", tree) == [] + ["Cousin"]
descendants("Grandfather", tree) == [] + ["Father"] + descendants("Father", tree) + ["Uncle"] + descendants("Uncle", tree)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [treelib](https://github.com/caesar0301/treelib) to achieve your desired result using the library's methods. Recursive functions are a great way to traverse a tree structure but it is very useful to have a good foundation for them to work on. Depending on what other functions you will be building, treelib can come in very handy indeed to avoid reinventing the wheel and losing time in the process. Especially if what you're working on is a family **tree**.

Treelib can be installed by `pip install treelib`.

## Code

```
>>> from treelib import Tree
>>> family = Tree()
>>> family.create_node("Great Grandfather", "Great Grandfather")  # root node
>>> family.create_node("Grandfather", "Grandfather", parent="Great Grandfather")
>>> family.create_node("Uncle", "Uncle", parent="Grandfather")
>>> family.create_node("Father", "Father", parent="Grandfather")
>>> family.create_node("Cousin", "Cousin", parent="Uncle")
>>> family.create_node("Son1", "Son1", parent="Father")
>>> family.create_node("Son2", "Son2", parent="Father")

>>> family.show() # tree.show() prints the tree in human-readable format

Great Grandfather
└── Grandfather
    ├── Father
    │   ├── Son1
    │   └── Son2
    └── Uncle
        └── Cousin

>>> def descendants(person, tree):
...     person_family = tree.subtree(person) # Create a subtree starting with person.
...     return person_family.size() - 1 # Subtracting 1 for Great Grandfather because tree.size() returns the total number of nodes in a tree.

>>> person = "Great Grandfather"
>>> print("{person} has {desc} descendants.".format(person=person, desc=descendants(person, family)))
Great Grandfather has 6 descendants.

>>> person = "Grandfather"
>>> print("{person} has {desc} descendants.".format(person=person, desc=descendants(person, family)))
Grandfather has 5 descendants.

>>> person = "Father"
>>> print("{person} has {desc} descendants.".format(person=person, desc=descendants(person, family)))
Father has 2 descendants.
```